# How to start a replica set without using localhost?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I'm trying to initialize a replica set with 3 nodes. While executing `rs.initiate()` I got the following error: "No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set ##### maps to this node"

If I try to set the first member to "localhost:27017" then I get the following error:  "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2"

How am I supposed to use my public ip to initiate the replica set?

Comment: I don't WANT to use localhost. I want to use my server's 3 public ips but it won't let me initiate the set that way. When I try to use the public ip it gives my the error that it can't map to this node.

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is to prepare the configuration that you want to use for the replica set in a document (for example `config`), and then passing this document as a parameter to the `rs.initiate(config)` method, like this:

```
config = {
    _id : "your_replica_set_name",
     members : [
         {_id : 0, host : "yourIpAddress:port1"},
         {_id : 1, host : "yourIpAddress:port2"},
         {_id : 2, host : "yourIpAddress:port3", arbiterOnly: true},
     ]
}

rs.initiate(config)
```

More details in [MongoDB - replSetInitiate command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetInitiate/)

Comment: I was about to downvote because I had the same problem and was still getting the error while passing a config just like this, but then I **specified the port number** 27017 even though it was the default, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to set your `bindIp:` directive to your server's IP address.

Below you can find the default config:

```
# network interfaces
net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```